# Using .join() in Python

Tags: python

Very simple and quick question. Take this list for example:

```
a = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']
','.join(a)
```

I would like to have 'and' instead of a comma before the last element of the list. So I would get:

> hello 1, hello 2 and hello 3

instead of....

> hello 1, hello 2, hello 3

Is there a way to accomplish this using `.join()`? I know I can just type it in the list for a simple example like this, but the list I need in my actual program comes from user input.

Comment: `', '.join(a[:-1]) + 'and ' + a[-1]` might be your best bet. There is no builtin function that does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In essence, you want to manipulate the two parts of the list separately, the first consisting of everything except the last string, and the other consisting of just the last one.

```
def my_func(lst):
    return ', '.join(lst[:-1])+' and '+lst[-1]
```

or using a lambda:

```
f = lambda x: ', '.join(x[:-1]) + ' and '+x[-1]
```

or if you just want it run once:

```
result = ', '.join(a[:-1]) + ' and ' + a[-1]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account empty lists or lists with just one element

Answer (score 3):

SnakesAndCoffee has the best way(s). Another (less useful) way:

```
>>> a = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']
>>> ' and '.join((', '.join(a[:-1]), a[-1]))
'hello1, hello2 and hello3'
```

Here you are using two `joins` - the inner `join` joins every element up until the second to last element with a comma. That string is then joined to the last element (`a[-1]`) using the outer `join`, which is `and`.

Comment: Thanks for an alternative method.

Comment: @TheDragonAce No problem at all :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle small lists as special cases:

```
def my_function(a):
    if a == []:
        return ""
    elif len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        return ', '.join(a[:-1])+' and '+ a[-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list=[] for i in range(no):   for j in range(no-i):
      list.append(j+1);   if(i!=0):
      for a in range(2*i-1):
          list.append(" ");   for k in range(no-i,0,-1):
      if(i==0 and k==no):
          pass;
      else:
          list.append(k);   list.append("\n");
```